# Yeoman Meanjs generator unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: proxy, npm, yeoman, meanjs

The company I work for uses a Zscaler proxy and I am trying to get the `meanjs` yeoman generator to work on my Windows 10 machine. So far I have managed to get `npm` to work by setting the `proxy`, `https-proxy` and the `registry` as follows:

```
npm config set proxy http://gateway.zscalerone.net/80
npm config set https-proxy http://gateway.zscalerone.net/80
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

however when I run:

```
yo meanjs
```

I get the following:

```
Running npm install for you....
This may take a couple minutes.
Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "cd mean && npm install"
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated jade@0.26.3: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@1.0.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.3.1 should be installed with -g
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
gyp ERR! stack     at Error (native)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1017:38)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:166:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket._init.ssl.onclienthello.ssl.oncertcb.TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:582:8)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSWrap.ssl.onclienthello.ssl.oncertcb.ssl.onnewsession.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:424:38)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ShaneH\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v4.4.5\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\ShaneH\Code\temp\mean\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 bufferutil@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 Exit status 1
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
gyp ERR! stack     at Error (native)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1017:38)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:166:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket._init.ssl.onclienthello.ssl.oncertcb.TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:582:8)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSWrap.ssl.onclienthello.ssl.oncertcb.ssl.onnewsession.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:424:38)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ShaneH\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v4.4.5\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\ShaneH\Code\temp\mean\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 Exit status 1
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download: https://node-inspector.s3.amazonaws.com/debug/v0.7.7/node-v46-win32-ia32.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for v8-debug@0.7.7 and node@4.4.5 (node-v46 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
gyp ERR! stack     at Error (native)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1017:38)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:166:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket._init.ssl.onclienthello.ssl.oncertcb.TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:582:8)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSWrap.ssl.onclienthello.ssl.oncertcb.ssl.onnewsession.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:424:38)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ShaneH\\Code\\temp\\mean\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\ShaneH\\Code\\temp\\mean\\node_modules\\v8-debug\\build\\debug\\v0.7.7\\node-v46-win32-ia32\\debug.node" "--module_name=debug" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\ShaneH\\Code\\temp\\mean\\node_modules\\v8-debug\\build\\debug\\v0.7.7\\node-v46-win32-ia32" "--msvs_version=2015"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\ShaneH\Code\temp\mean\node_modules\v8-debug
gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\ShaneH\Code\temp\mean\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\ShaneH\Code\temp\mean\node_modules\v8-debug\build\debug\v0.7.7\node-v46-win32-ia32\debug.node --module_name=debug --module_path=C:\Users\ShaneH\Code\temp\mean\node_modules\v8-debug\build\debug\v0.7.7\node-v46-win32-ia32 --msvs_version=2015' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ShaneH\Code\temp\mean\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ShaneH\\Code\\temp\\mean\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\ShaneH\Code\temp\mean\node_modules\v8-debug
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.5
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.28
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.12
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@6.0.2 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-react@^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.6
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! v8-debug@0.7.7 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the v8-debug@0.7.7 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the v8-debug package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs v8-debug
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls v8-debug
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ShaneH\Code\temp\mean\npm-debug.log

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:213:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
```

Which seems to indicate that it can't connect via `https` to

https://node-inspector.s3.amazonaws.com/debug/v0.7.7/node-v46-win32-ia32.tar.gz

I have tried setting up `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables, but this doesn't seem to have made a difference. I am also able to browse to that URL in a browser without an issue.

I assume the error has to do with the way Zscaler is handling https. Any help would be greatly appreciated.